# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

My jboss EAP 7.2.7 is not able to start due to the following error:

```
2022-04-01 11:45:28.783)~L(:ERROR)~L(:JBOSS)~L(:org.jboss.msc.service.fail)~L(:)~L(:)~L(:)~L(:)~L(:)~L(:)~L(:MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.worker: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.worker: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731) [jboss-msc-1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559) [jboss-msc-1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) [jboss-threads-2.3.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985) [jboss-threads-2.3.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487) [jboss-threads-2.3.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378) [jboss-threads-2.3.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XNIO001001: No XNIO provider found
    at org.xnio.Xnio.doGetInstance(Xnio.java:261) [xnio-api-3.7.6.SP2-redhat-00001.jar:3.7.6.SP2-redhat-00001]
    at org.xnio.Xnio.getInstance(Xnio.java:194) [xnio-api-3.7.6.SP2-redhat-00001.jar:3.7.6.SP2-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.ManagementWorkerService.start(ManagementWorkerService.java:51)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739) [jboss-msc-1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701) [jboss-msc-1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001]
```

Comment: What kind of configuration changes have you made? That seems odd as does the log format.

Comment: I used the default JBoss configuration. I am really disappointed to say this but the problem was resolved by just restarting my pc.